# How to restore a model by filename in Tensorflow r12?

Tags: tensorflow

I have run the distributed mnist example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py

Though I have set the

`saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=0)`

In previous release, like r11, I was able to run over each check point model and evaluate the precision of the model. This gave me a plot of the progress of the precision versus global steps (or iterations).

Prior to r12, tensorflow checkpoint models were saved in two files, `model.ckpt-1234` and `model-ckpt-1234.meta`. One could restore a model by passing the `model.ckpt-1234` filename like so `saver.restore(sess,'model.ckpt-1234')`.

However, I've noticed that in r12, there are now three output files `model.ckpt-1234.data-00000-of-000001`, `model.ckpt-1234.index`, and `model.ckpt-1234.meta`.

I see that the the restore documentation says that a path such as `/train/path/model.ckpt` should be given to restore instead of a filename. Is there any way to load one checkpoint file at a time to evaluate it? I have tried passing the `model.ckpt-1234.data-00000-of-000001`, `model.ckpt-1234.index`, and `model.ckpt-1234.meta` files, but get errors like below:

`W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open logdir/2016-12-08-13-54/model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?`

`NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Tensor name "hid_b" not found in checkpoint files logdir/2016-12-08-13-54/model.ckpt-0.index
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]`

`W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open logdir/2016-12-08-13-54/model.ckpt-0.meta: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?`

I'm running on OSX Sierra with tensorflow r12 installed via pip.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I also used Tensorlfow r0.12 and I didn't think there is any issue for saving and restoring model. The following is a simple code that you can have a try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35), name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35), name="v2")

# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.

  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Do some work with the model
```

although in r0.12, the checkpoint is stored in multiple files, you can restore it by using the common prefix, which is 'model.ckpt' in your case.

Comment: I have to add tf.train.import_meta_graph 
`with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")`

Comment: I think your comment in the last 2 lines should be placed on top and in bold. It's the most important part to see in a glance if your answer matches someone else problem.

Answer (score 5):

The R12 has changed the checkpoint format. You should save the model in the old format.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.protobuf import saver_pb2
...
saver = tf.train.Saver(write_version = saver_pb2.SaverDef.V1)
saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt', global_step = step)
```

According to the [TensorFlow v0.12.0 RC0’s release note](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases):

> New checkpoint format becomes the default in tf.train.Saver. Old V1
>   checkpoints continue to be readable; controlled by the write_version
>   argument, tf.train.Saver now by default writes out in the new V2
>   format. It significantly reduces the peak memory required and latency
>   incurred during restore.

see details in [my blog](http://votec.top/2016/12/24/tensorflow-r12-tf-train-Saver/).

Comment: what exactly does "data-0000-of-0001" part mean?

Answer (score 4):

You can restore the model like this:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./src/models/20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.meta')
            saver.restore(sess,'./src/models/20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000'))
```

Where the path '/src/models/20170512-110547/' contains three files:

```
model-20170512-110547.meta
model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.index
model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000.data-00000-of-00001
```

And if in one directory there are more than one checkpoints,eg: there are checkpoint files in  the path 
./20170807-231648/:

```
checkpoint     
model-20170807-231648-0.data-00000-of-00001   
model-20170807-231648-0.index    
model-20170807-231648-0.meta   
model-20170807-231648-100000.data-00000-of-00001   
model-20170807-231648-100000.index   
model-20170807-231648-100000.meta
```

you can see that there are two checkpoints, so you can use this:

```
saver =    tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/tools/Tools/raoqiang/facenet/models/facenet/20170807-231648/model-20170807-231648-0.meta')

saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/tools/Tools/raoqiang/facenet/models/facenet/20170807-231648/'))
```

Comment: Sorry, the optimizer is the matter, I found that there were some constraints that you can't restore a model directly  from a directory if there is only one check point, but you can try this:

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/tools/Tools/raoqiang/facenet/src/models/20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.meta')
                saver.restore(sess,'/home/tools/Tools/raoqiang/facenet/src/models/20170512-110547/model-20170512-110547.ckpt-250000')

Answer (score 1):

OK, I can answer my own question. What I found was that my python script was adding an extra '/' to my path so I was executing:
saver.restore(sess,'/path/to/train//model.ckpt-1234')

somehow that was causing a problem with tensorflow.

When I removed it, calling:
saver.restore(sess,'/path/to/trian/model.ckpt-1234')

it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

use only model.ckpt-1234

at least it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to TF and met the same issue. After reading Yuan Ma's comments, I copied the '.index' to the same 'train\ckpt' folder together with '.data-00000-of-00001' file. Then it worked! 
So, the .index file is sufficient when restoring the models.
I used TF on Win7, r12.