# Tensorflow & Keras can't load .ckpt save

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

So I am using the ModelCheckpoint callback to save the best epoch of a model I am training. It saves with no errors, but when I try to load it, I get the error:

```
2019-07-27 22:58:04.713951: W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open C:\Users\Riley\PycharmProjects\myNN\cp.ckpt: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

I have tried using the absolute/full path, but no luck. I'm sure I could use EarlyStopping, but I'd still like to understand why I am getting the error. Here is my code:

```java
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import statistics

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = np.load("dataset.npy", allow_pickle=True)

train_images = train_images / 255
test_images = test_images / 255

train_labels = list(map(float, train_labels))
test_labels = list(map(float, test_labels))
train_labels = [i/10 for i in train_labels]
test_labels = [i/10 for i in test_labels]

'''
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(128, 128)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

'''

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)

])

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01),
    metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])

train_images = train_images.reshape(328, 128, 128, 1)
test_images = test_images.reshape(82, 128, 128, 1)

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=100, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("cp.ckpt", monitor='mean_absolute_error', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)])

model.load_weights("cp.ckpt")

predictions = model.predict(test_images)

totalDifference = 0
for i in range(82):
    print("%s: %s" % (test_labels[i] * 10, predictions[i] * 10))
    totalDifference += abs(test_labels[i] - predictions[i])

avgDifference = totalDifference / 8.2

print("\n%s\n" % avgDifference)
print("Time Elapsed:")
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; you are saving whole model, while trying to load only weights, that's not how it works.

### Explanation

Your model's `fit`:

```
model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[
        keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            "cp.ckpt", monitor="mean_absolute_error", save_best_only=True, verbose=1
        )
    ],
)
```

As `save_weights=False` by default in `ModelCheckpoint`, you are saving whole model to `.ckpt`.

BTW. File should be named `.hdf5` or `.hf5` as it's [`Hierarchical Data Format 5`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format). As Windows is not extension-agnostic you may run into some problems if `tensorflow` / `keras` relies on extension on this OS.

On the other hand you are loading the model's weights only, while the file contains **whole model**:

```
model.load_weights("cp.ckpt")
```

Tensorflow's checkpointing (`.cp`) mechanism is different from Keras's (`.hdf5`), so watch out for that (there are plans to integrate them more closely, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/checkpoints) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/saved_model)).

### Solution

So, either use the callback as you currently do, **BUT** use `model.load("model.hdf5")` or add `save_weights_only=True` argument to `ModelCheckpoint`:

```
model.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    epochs=100,
    callbacks=[
        keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            "weights.hdf5",
            monitor="mean_absolute_error",
            save_best_only=True,
            verbose=1,
            save_weights_only=True,  # Specify this
        )
    ],
)
```

and you can use your `model.load_weights("weights.hdf5")`.

Answer (score 2):

`model.load_weights` will not work here. Reason is mentioned in the above answer.
You can load weights by this code. Load your model first and than load weights. I hope this code will help you out

```
import tensorflow as tf

model=dense_net()
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(
step=tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.int64),  net=model)
ckpt.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint("/kaggle/working/training_1/cp.ckpt.data-00001-of-00002"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35), name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35), name="v2")

# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.

  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
  # Do some work with the model
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048819/how-to-restore-a-model-by-filename-in-tensorflow-r12)

Comment: Thanks! But do I really need to alter my whole code just to fix this? Unless I am missing something, the documentation says mine should work.

Comment: Keep this code and write your model in `# Do some work with the model.`