# TensorFlow: How to load weights trained with an older version of TensorFlow in TensorFlow 1.14?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a bunch of models with TensorFlow 1.10. Back then, the weights for a model were saved to two files with extensions `.hdf5.index` and `.hdf5.data-00000-of-00001`. I am now trying to make the switch to TensorFlow 1.14, but loading the weights (with `model.load_weights(weights + ".hdf5")` now throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 73, in <module>
    model.load_weights(DIR + "weights/weights.hdf5")
  File ".../python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 162, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File ".../python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1412, in load_weights
    with h5py.File(filepath, 'r') as f:
  File ".../python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 394, in __init__
    swmr=swmr)
  File ".../python3.5/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 170, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'weights.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

TensorFlow 1.14 just saves weights to one `.hd5f` file, so I assume that's what it expects. I tried omitting the additional parts of the `.hdf5.index` and `.hdf5.data-00000-of-00001` extensions, but the same error persist. Is there any way to open my old weights files?

Comment: If it's not in your Recycle Bin / Trash, perhaps you could use a file undeletion program that could look for the a file like ~eights.hdf5 .

Comment: I haven't deleted anything. I only have files with those two weird extensions.

Comment: When saving weights an hdf5 file, the result should be a single file, as you are observing under tf 1.14. The `.index` and `.data-0000-of-0001` suffices of your weights files suggest that they are actually stored in a different format. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save_weights

Comment: Also maybe check this anwer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237671/tensorflow-keras-cant-load-ckpt-save